# Incorrect IP used for outbound traffic in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5

I'm having an issue that i've been racking my brain over and I'm unsure if this is a problem or if its something by design. I have several HTTPS websites on my web server (IIS 8.5) and they all have their own IP addresses. The problem that I'm having is that a user will conntect to website 1 (10.1.1.3 for example) and an outbound call to the database or web service will occur using website 2's IP address (10.1.1.4) instead of using its own IP address or the primary address of the server (10.1.1.2). So when you are looking at logs, it makes it look like website 2 is connecting to all of these different servers when it has no ties to those servers at all in the code. Am I missing something? This causes a problem for firewall rules and logging.

Comment: I would suggest searching "set primary IP on Windows Server" and verify that 10.1.1.2 really is your primary (my guess is your server thinks 10.1.1.4 is).

IIS acts more like a PBX in that it will listen and route to sites based on IP address and/or host name but it's not really creating a static connection with the web application. Once your web app code starts executing its own outbound connections, it functions like any other app on the box.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find the fix in this article https://secura.cloud/technical-insight/windows-server/set-primary-ip-address-windows-server-2012#.VOe_0EfF98E

Answer (score 0):

IP's for outbound traffic are potentially pulled from any of the addresses on the box. There are ways to change this behavior, but they require some code to implement. The source address can be overridden for the request, by using the [ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.bindipendpointdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx) to set a [BindIPEndPoint Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.bindipendpoint(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    public delegate IPEndPoint BindIPEndPoint(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount);

    private IPEndPoint BindIPEndPointCallback(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
    {
        IPAddress localIPAddress;

        if (retryCount < 3)
        {
            localIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4");
        }
        else
        {
            localIPAddress = IPAddress.Any;
        }


        return new IPEndPoint(localIPAddress, 0);
    }

request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new System.Net.BindIPEndPoint(BindIPEndPointCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed, followed user2638401's advice and found this https://secura.cloud/technical-insight/windows-server/set-primary-ip-address-windows-server-2012#.VOe_0EfF98E